# Excel substitute a cell and add add a letter/number

Tags: excel, automation, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a formula that can do three things within the same cell.
The formula needs to get a value from another cell, but only the middle part (which can be solved with the substitute function). Next, it needs to add a letter at the start, and another number at the end.

Example:

I have the following three values:

1. 201642A
2. 201142A
3. 201342A

The values need to be converted to the following

1. A16421
2. A11421
3. A13421

As you can see, the first two numbers, "20" have been replaced with "A", and the "A" at the end has been replaced with "1".

Reason:
I need to do this for hundreds of records across multiple columns so a bit of automation would save me alot of time.

[Here is an example in Excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt4tn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`=if(left(A1,2)=20,"A") & mid(A1,3,4) & if(right(a1,1)="A",1)`

Comment: It works! However, I needed to translate the functions to that of my own language (Dutch), change the "," to ";" and add a false value, so it always changes into the value i want it to.

Here is the formula:
=ALS(LINKS(A76; 2)= 20;"A";"A") & DEEL(A76;3;4) & ALS(RECHTS(A76;1)="A";2;2)